How to keep text always facing to viewport?
How to keep texts always align to viewport? I mean viewport, not a camera.
Just like this


Easiest way, parent the camera to the viewport and then the text to the camera

example https://imgur.com/a/iGcTa26

As I understood he wants to avoid moving the text outside of the viewport, while facing to cam.
